# Symfony & Doctrine Migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Here is where I'm stuck :

I'm calling an api that execute a doctrine migration, using the latest version.

It runs a command.

When I execute the command manually here is the output (THE JOB IS DONE):
 == Configuration

```
>> Name:                                               Application Migrations
>> Database Driver:                                    pdo_sqlsrv
>> Database Name:                                      xxxxxxxxxx
>> Configuration Source:                               manually configured
>> Version Table Name:                                 Dsys_migration_versions
>> Version Column Name:                                version
>> Migrations Namespace:                               Application\Migrations
>> Migrations Directory:                               /var/www/xxxx/app/DoctrineMigrations
>> Previous Version:                                    (20170503101946CreateSettingTable)
>> Current Version:                                     (20170621150818CreateCalculatedfieldQuery)
>> Next Version:                                       Already at latest version
>> Latest Version:                                      (20170621150818CreateCalculatedfieldQuery)
>> Executed Migrations:                                19
>> Executed Unavailable Migrations:                    0
>> Available Migrations:                               19
>> New Migrations:                                     0
```

== Available Migration Versions

```
>>  (20170307111115CreateCustomTableTable)             migrated
>>  (20170307111322CreateCustomFieldTable)             migrated
>>  (20170307111324CreatePresetFieldTable)             migrated
>>  (20170307111326CreateDimensionTable)               migrated
>>  (20170307111328CreateCustomFieldChoiceTable)       migrated
>>  (20170307111329CreateImportScheduleTable)          migrated
>>  (20170307111331CreateMappedFieldTable)             migrated
>>  (20170307111332CreateImportTaskTable)              migrated
>>  (20170307111334CreateSegmentationQueryTable)       migrated
>>  (20170307111335CreateSegmentationQueryJoinTable)   migrated
>>  (20170307111336CreateCalculatedFieldSettingTable)  migrated
>>  (20170307111338CreateBlacklistTable)               migrated
>>  (20170307151829CreateCalculatedFieldFilterTable)   migrated
>>  (20170315105949CreateImportTable)                  migrated
>>  (20170403134126CreateFamilyTable)                  migrated
>>  (20170410124309CreateUserTable)                    migrated
>>  (20170412103331CreateCalculatedFieldJoinTable)     migrated
>>  (20170503101946CreateSettingTable)                 migrated
>>  (20170621150818CreateCalculatedfieldQuery)         migrated
```

When I call the api that runs the command (seems to follow the exact same path) (JOB NOT DONE) :

== Configuration

```
>> Name:                                               Application Migrations
>> Database Driver:                                    pdo_sqlsrv
>> Database Name:                                      xxxxxxxxxxxx
>> Configuration Source:                               manually configured
>> Version Table Name:                                 Dsys_migration_versions
>> Version Column Name:                                version
>> Migrations Namespace:                               Application\Migrations
>> Migrations Directory:                               /var/www/xxxxxx/app/DoctrineMigrations
>> Previous Version:                                   Already at first version
>> Current Version:                                    0
>> Next Version:                                        (20170307111115CreateCustomTableTable)
>> Latest Version:                                      (20170621150818CreateCalculatedfieldQuery)
>> Executed Migrations:                                0
>> Executed Unavailable Migrations:                    0
>> Available Migrations:                               19
>> New Migrations:                                     19
```

== Available Migration Versions

```
>>  (20170307111115CreateCustomTableTable)             not migrated
>>  (20170307111322CreateCustomFieldTable)             not migrated
>>  (20170307111324CreatePresetFieldTable)             not migrated
>>  (20170307111326CreateDimensionTable)               not migrated
>>  (20170307111328CreateCustomFieldChoiceTable)       not migrated
>>  (20170307111329CreateImportScheduleTable)          not migrated
>>  (20170307111331CreateMappedFieldTable)             not migrated
>>  (20170307111332CreateImportTaskTable)              not migrated
>>  (20170307111334CreateSegmentationQueryTable)       not migrated
>>  (20170307111335CreateSegmentationQueryJoinTable)   not migrated
>>  (20170307111336CreateCalculatedFieldSettingTable)  not migrated
>>  (20170307111338CreateBlacklistTable)               not migrated
>>  (20170307151829CreateCalculatedFieldFilterTable)   not migrated
>>  (20170315105949CreateImportTable)                  not migrated
>>  (20170403134126CreateFamilyTable)                  not migrated
>>  (20170410124309CreateUserTable)                    not migrated
>>  (20170412103331CreateCalculatedFieldJoinTable)     not migrated
>>  (20170503101946CreateSettingTable)                 not migrated
>>  (20170621150818CreateCalculatedfieldQuery)         not migrated
```

I can perform the awaiting migration through a bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate command. I have no clue why is the job not done without that.

Here is the last function calling doctrine:migrations:migrate :

```
private function migrateDatabase(OutputInterface $output, string $version = 'latest')
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate');
    $arguments = ['version' => $version];
    $inputCommand = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $inputCommand->setInteractive(false);
    if ($command->run($inputCommand, $output) !== 0) {
        $output->writeln('<error>Fail : errors in database migrations.</error>');
    }
}
```

If i dump the $output while calling the api it prompte : no migrations aviailable. When obviously in constole a doctrine:migrations:status output 19migrations awaiting...

Plus, you have to know that, this damn thing, works when a target some database, but fail when i target others. i absolutely cant tell the difference since they are copy and past of each others... that's why i need to debug, i could ignore it and just see this as a random bug but when this thing goes live, i dont want a bad surprise.

[EDIT]
Its the getMigrationsToExecute($direction, $to) that returns empty on the case i'm debugging, starting to look up why. If you have any clue.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do the `Database name` ouput from api and console are same ? Doctrine use a table (migration_versions) to store which migration have been executed.

Comment: yep its the same... i've got setInteractive to false also so that's not about the prompt neither in theory.
Plus i've got store proc that are correctly created on the api call, so it confirm that DB is the right one.

Comment: Can you show us the part of code which execute the latest doctrine migrations on your api ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was going wrong, didnt find any solution yet.

While digging in the limbs of symfony and doctrine i stopped on this function :

```
public function getMigratedVersions()
{
    $this->connect();
    $this->createMigrationTable();

    $ret = $this->connection->fetchAll("SELECT " . $this->migrationsColumnName . " FROM " . $this->migrationsTableName);

    return array_map('current', $ret);
}
```

and it returns something, when it should not.

WHY ? because its performing on the wrong database..... WHY ? I don't know, 
i dumped $this->connection->getDatabase(); and its set to the correct one, but performing queries on another.

That's the point now, why does it not select the correct database even though it's correctly fed ?

Cheers.